# How can I modify a matlab/simulink mask depending of the state of the mask?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to set the Enabled state of a check box in a matlab/simulink mask (GUI) depending on the state of another check box. In other words: if check box A is checked, check box B shall be disabled (greyed).
I tried to use a callback function on check box A:

```
box_A = get_param(gcb, 'checkBoxA');
m = Simulink.Mask.get(gcb);
box_B = m.getParameter('checkBoxB');

if strcmp(box_A, 'on')
    box_B.set('Enabled', 'off');
end
```

But when I open the mask, I get an error:

> -->Error evaluating 'MaskCallback' callback of TEST block (mask) 'test_simulink /Test test'. -->Invalid inputs specified for method 'set' -->Attempt to modify mask parameter name of block 'test_simulink/Test test' in its MaskCallbacks. Changing mask parameter name as part of MaskCallbacks is not allowed.

How can I accomplish my initial goal?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with code. Have you checked whether parameter names are accurate and whether you are able to do the same thing at MATLAB command line?

Comment: From the matlab command line, it works, i.e. after I issue box_B.set('Enabled', 'off'); and open the GUI again, check box B is greyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution; the trick is not to use the set function, but to assign to the Enabled property:

```
box_A = get_param(gcb, 'checkBoxA');
m = Simulink.Mask.get(gcb);
box_B = m.getParameter('checkBoxB');

if strcmp(box_A, 'on')
    box_B.Enabled = 'off';
else
    box_B.Enabled = 'on';
end
```